# Angular Material and Kendo doesn't work with Module Federation Plugin: Bootstrap call not found

Tags: angular, angular-material, kendo-ui-angular2, micro-frontend, webpack-module-federation

I built a microfrontend application using Angular CLI and Module Federation Plugin.
When I try to install Angular Material or Kendo, I've got this problem:
`Bootstrap call not found`

I followed this [link](https://github.com/angular-architects/module-federation-plugin/issues/93)  to resolve this problem. Unfortunately, I've got further problems:

1. When I install Angular Material, I've got this error:

`Your project is not using the default builders for "build". The Angular Material schematics cannot add a theme to the workspace configuration if the builder has been changed.`

2. When I install Kendo, I've got this error:

`Skipping installation: Package already installed. File node_modules/@progress/kendo-angular-buttons/package.json does not exist.`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Before installing the libraries, I replaced the contents of main.ts with the contents of bootstrap.ts:

main.ts:

```
/*import('./bootstrap')
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
*/

import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

After installing the libraries, I restored its contents:

```
import('./bootstrap')
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

This isn't the best solution, but it works!

Answer (score 0):

Check your angular.json file. For me, the error "Package already installed" came due to having same named library already there in the angular.json. Removing from there, I was able to work without getting any errors.